# Simple ASP.NET with VB.NET - Could not load type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a c# guy but I need to get a small vb.net test harness working. For the life of me I can't get this to work, and can't discover why. Here's the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Source Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .vb:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

Always the error "Could not load type '_Default'." I even turned the folder into a true Application in IIS but it made no difference. What am I missing?

What am I missing?

Comment: Did I built what? These 2 simplistic aspx pages? Just copied from someplace online. I have a complex c# app that I need the vb.net harness to call into.

Comment: Web applications need to be compiled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below two -

1. If your code-behind contains a `namespace` then modify your `inherits` attribute in Page directive as `Inherits="namespace._Default"`.
2. If it doesn't, simply remove this `Inherits` attribute from Page Directive.

Comment: Thanks Atanu. Removing Inherits solved it. That's really all I needed. I don't understand the 2 downvotes. It's a legit question with a simple answer.

Comment: Please remember that this kind of issues are faced mostly while framework migration and this is a work-around only. You should not remove `Inherits` attribute in case of developing a page from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `Codebehind` attributename to `CodeFile` worked for me:

**vb**

```
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"
```

**C#**

```
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
```